# Plot absolute value inequalities - number line

Tags: plotting, inequalities

I'd like to ask you about the way to draw the number line for absolute value inequalities.

Is there any built-in tool?

In this case the input was $|x-6| > 3$.

My point is to achieve something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [`NumberLinePlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NumberLinePlot.html).

```
NumberLinePlot[Abs[x - 6] > 3, {x, -3, 15}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]